# Coldfusion to Rails migration with Java code unchanged

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, coldfusion, jruby

We've built a webapp using plain Coldfusion 9 (serving html content) and Java (backend work and connecting to WebServices). We're expecting about 50 000 visitors a day, up to 200 requests per minute. Production servers are running on Windows. 
The problem is that we're getting tired and angry because of painful CF code.

Our idea is to replace the CF layer with Ruby on Rails. The java side should be left untouched, because it's well written, reliable, fast and covered with automated tests.

So my question is: how would you approach this problem in details?

1. Is JRuby the only option?
2. Will invoking our jar-packaged Java code be still fast enough?
3. Is Linux required along with switching to Rails? (I don't like Rails on Windows)
4. What about scalability? Do you recommend Sinatra to handle our traffic?
5. Will it be possible to place this configuration in a cloud?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what your painful CF code is? Perhaps the problem isn't ColdFusion, but how you developed your application in it.

Comment: I think one of the popular choices of http module 'passenger' do not support windows environment.

Comment: No framework was used, so there're sqls mixed with html code. And no MVC, no OOP. We've been thinking of re-writing the CF layer from scratch, but it's also a good moment to change the technology. We all know and like Rails, so it was the first thing we thought of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is JRuby the only option?

Don't speak in absolutes! :) JRuby has the benefit of being able to call Java libraries like CF, but it's still an emerging platform, albeit one with great potential on the JVM.

> Will invoking our jar-packaged Java
>   code be still fast enough?

If you are still going to run on a JVM language like CF or JRuby then I would say yes.

> Is Linux required along with switching
>   to Rails? (I don't like Rails on
>   Windows)

Linux is not required for JRuby (see [here](http://www.iowaosum.com/install-jruby)) - remember JRuby is just another JVM language and the benefit of the JVM is platform independence. If you are going for plain Rails I would recommend going over to Linux - I've tried using Rails on  Windows before and it's not pretty. Everything you read in terms of Rails tutorials etc. will assume a favour of Linux.

> What about scalability? Do you
>   recommend Sinatra to handle our
>   traffic?

Sinatra is a very slimmed down framework which essentially uses simple regex routing rules. I would use it for small projects, but for a production application that is likely to grow, then no. You are better off getting the organisational benefits of Rails.

> Will it be possible to place this
>   configuration in a cloud?

I [believe](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/jruby-on-appcloud-available-through-beta-program/) Engine Yard do JRuby hosting. Heroku do Rails PaaS hosting. Heroku might not be a good match if you are using JRuby or calling Java from JRuby, but for a plain Rails application it's very cool.

And as others have pointed out - CF is not the problem, the problem is how your application was written and organised. You can write crap Rails code too, remember.

Hoep all that helps you somewhat with your decision.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. It really clarified the choice for us.
We'd try with Rails on JRuby to have the access to the wonderful world of Cucumber, ActiveRecord and other gems, but if we fail on performance tests, we'll switch to CFwheels.

Comment: JRuby should be able to handle the load just fine. I recommend setting the min and max runtimes to 1 in the config which enables multithreaded mode, and Rails flies!

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing you should give the ColdFusion on Wheels framework a try. It's VERY inspired by Rails and you could easily drop your current app into the framework and then slowly convert it over to MVC.

Check it out at: http://cfwheels.org/

Comment: +1 - you should really not blame a language due to someone's poor implementation of it.  Like most here I know dozens of languages, CF is by far one of the most powerful - which also makes it dangerous in the hands of the inexperienced.  Try it for a month and you'll love it.

Comment: One of our team members has been trying out CFWheels for a while, but his experience whas not so nice. We miss Rails Cucumber a lot and ActiveRecord tricks. CFWheels looks promising for our application, but it certainly doesn't have the power of Rails.
Thanks for the comments about our poor implementation. I should've mentioned that I've taken over an existing CF project.

Comment: Yay! [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) can be used outside Rails! (http://jamieonsoftware.com/journal/2011/1/2/high-level-testing-php-applications-with-cucumber.html)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ciaran Archer's thoughts for the most part, and will point out a project where I incrementally convert a Spring application to Rails. You will have to use your imagination to figure out how to convert your messy CF views to Rails, but you can at least look to see how you might use your Java backend in a Rails environment.

https://github.com/nicksieger/refactoring-to-rails